# Open multiple firefox tabs from command line

Tags: command-line, firefox

I'm trying to open `firefox` with two tabs from the command line, with two separate web addresses.  So far I'm having no luck.

```
firefox -new-tab https://www.evernote.com/Home.action -new-tab http://www.gmail.com
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Oops.  I just found the answer.  You need to add a `-url` after each `-new-tab'.

```
firefox -new-tab -url https://www.evernote.com/Home.action -new-tab -url http://www.gmail.com
```

Now it works.  Hope this can help somebody.

Comment: Cool. That would be very usefull in Chrome as well.

Comment: For macOS users: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --new-tab https://google.com`

Answer (score 12):

You no longer need to add `-url`, simply write `firefox` followed by space-separated URLs.

Example:

```
firefox mail.google.com askubuntu.com stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Personally, I run it at startup using CTRL+R to recall the line and with a & at the end of the command to detach the firefox session from the terminal - just a suggestion.

Comment: This is not working for me. The only change that I did was that I have added a new profile in firefox and set it as the default. Now when I try the above solution, I get the following error

```Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.```

Firefox is not stuck though. Both the new profile and the default one are working fine from the UI.

Answer (score 8):

Create a file containing list of URLs called `url.txt`:

```
http://www.url1.xxx
http://www.url2.xxx
http://www.url3.xxx
```

Firefox uses the new-tab command, so you could pass the URLs in the file to the browser like so:

```
xargs -a url.txt firefox -new-tab "$line"
```

Comment: @Maythus awesome

Comment: this approach generates the same popup error cited by @livinston

Comment: this approach generates the same popup error cited by @livinston

additional info: I am using firefox 96. This issue only appeared somewhere after version 90 (or with whatever ubuntu 20.04.3 updates were made in this timeframe). Not clear to me if this is a firefox issue or an ubuntu one, but the fact that I get the same error when running the equivalent command for vivaldi, brave, and opera makes me think is an issue brought upon us by GNOME or ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374403/after-firefox-94-update-cli-launch-half-broken