# Open Chromium tabs from command line

Tags: command-line, chromium

I'd like to open Chromium Browser with a set of defined tabs, probably set in a favourite folder.
Is there anyway to achieve that?

It would be similar to the Firefox behaviour  @Andy j  defined in https://askubuntu.com/a/617935/209229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use similar methods with Chrome(ium) as well. You don't need to use `-new-tab` or `-url` in this case. The following command will launch Chromium with three new tabs open, or just will open these tabs if Chromium is already launched:

```
chromium-browser firefox.com ubuntu.com duckduckgo.com &
```

- <sup>The ampersand `&` will push the process to the background if there is not already opened Chromium browser, and you will be able to use or close the terminal independently of Chromium. Otherwise it does not hinder.</sup>

[image]

Comment: Yes, this would most likely be preferable. Editing to cite above.

Comment: Awesome! You did a much better job formatting that than I did! xD Thank you very much. :D