# Automatically Start up in Chrome

Tags: system, startup-applications, startupmanager

Im using a NUC as a kiosk, is there a way to automatically open to a chrome webpage at startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you will have to open `Startup Applications`.

1. Click on `Add` and enter a Name like `Open Chrome`
2. Then as command you enter `chromium-browser google.com`
3. Click on `Add` to confirm

- Instead of google.com you should enter the Website you want to open.
- You can replace `chromium-browser` with chrome depending on what you use

You can log out and back in to confirm it worked.

I got my information from this post: [Open Chromium tabs from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953855/open-chromium-tabs-from-command-line)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm very new to the world of linux, that worked perfectly

Comment: If that solved your problem, you should accept the answer as the solution. Thank you very much for your Feedback!