# Open Chrome history using terminal commands

Tags: command-line, chromium, raspberrypi

How can I open Chrome history using terminal commands.

It is similar to [Open multiple firefox tabs from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617933/open-multiple-firefox-tabs-from-command-line) but that kind of solution is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't open a history tab as you requested but you may be interested in trying googles [history API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history).

As far as I can tell you can't just open the history tab via the command line. You can access the information in the history via the API mentioned above but according to [this google page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) entering `chrome://history` in the URL should bring you to the history (which it does). However, I have not been able to get it to work from the command line using 
`google-chrome -new-tab chrome://history`

Comment: Same here. But since there's a shortcut when opening chrome, can you just open history tab by inputting a shortcut command like "Ctrl+H" ? If yes what would the command be like?

Comment: @LarryKyntiewnamSyiemlieh Maybe, but you will note that "Ctrl+H" only opens a history tab if there is none open if there is one or more open it will open the first existing one. Because of this, I'm guessing you may have to download the API to access that ability.

Comment: @LarryKyntiewnamSyiemlieh is this something you want to do just for your self or is this something that is for a product you are working on? I'm just wondering if there are other ways of doing it using a browser shortcut or something.

Comment: This is for my project. I'm trying to develop a voice recognition program using python in raspberry pi. This is mainly focused on getting output from voice inputs only. So while running the python script, I can say open YouTube then the browser opens up YouTube without me doing it manually