# After firefox 94 update, CLI launch (half) broken

Tags: firefox

setup:

- ubuntu 20.04.3, regularly updated (including firefox)
- firefox 94.0 (just updated, within past week, via aptitude / ubuntu's firefox channel)

problem:

- Before upgrading to v94, I regularly made use of
  `$ firefox URL`
  ...which launched firefox if it was not running, or simply spawned a new tab in an existing firefox session.
- Now, since upgrading to v94, I notice 2 things:

  - It takes several seconds for anything to observable to happen.
  - After that time lapse, I get this pop-up error message: "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile."

Perhaps unrelated, but fishy behavior that began only recently in ubuntu 20.04 (observable on multiple workstations) and *feels* related: `gedit TEXTFILE` takes ~1min to spawn a new text edit window, where it used to be instantaneous.

Apologies if this was in an update log somewhere that I did not read...

Comment: As it was pointed out to me in my question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376845/firefox-94-when-ran-from-a-crontab-claims-already-running-but-is-not-responding#comment2372045_1376845 that you will have to use the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` for the call for Firefox to work.